# Sucuri SiteCheck failing on domain with iThemes Security Pro plugin

Tags: plugins

I have the plugin iThemes Security Pro installed on a couple of my websites. Recently, I've noticed that my Sucuri SiteCheck (both automated and not) scans are failing, but I have no idea why that is the case. The log is also ambiguous, telling me: `Unable to properly scan your site. Timeout reached`.

Below is the raw log the plugin gives me. Appreciate if anyone can tell me what the problem is. I don't have firewalls enabled, either on the plugin or on the Apache level, though I have ModSecurity enabled.

ModSecurity's logs don't give me any errors whenever I try a SiteCheck though, so it seems like the request is not even getting to Apache.

```
id               => 15729
module           => malware
type             => warning
code             => sucuri-system-error
timestamp        => 2019-07-13 09:06:55
init_timestamp   => 2019-07-13 09:06:48
remote_ip        => 10.20.30.40
user_id          => 1
url              => https://domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
memory_current   => 21832592
memory_peak      => 21915880
data             => Array
    results   => Array
        BLACKLIST   => Array
            INFO   => Array
                0   => Array
                    0   => Domain clean by Google Safe Browsing: www.domain.com
                    1   => https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=domain.com
                1   => Array
                    0   => Domain clean by Norton Safe Web: www.domain.com
                    1   => https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=domain.com
                2   => Array
                    0   => Domain clean by McAfee: www.domain.com
                    1   => https://www.siteadvisor.com/sitereport.html?url=domain.com
                3   => Array
                    0   => Domain clean by Sucuri Labs: www.domain.com
                    1   => https://labs.sucuri.net/?blacklist=domain.com
                4   => Array
                    0   => Domain clean by ESET: www.domain.com
                    1   => https://labs.sucuri.net/?eset
                5   => Array
                    0   => Domain clean by PhishTank: www.domain.com
                    1   => https://www.phishtank.com
                6   => Array
                    0   => Domain clean by Yandex: www.domain.com
                    1   => https://www.yandex.com/infected?url=domain.com
                7   => Array
                    0   => Domain clean by Opera: www.domain.com
                    1   => https://www.opera.com
                8   => Array
                    0   => Domain clean by Spamhaus: www.domain.com
                    1   => http://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/domain.com
        SCAN        => Array
            DOMAIN   => Array
                0   => www.domain.com
            INPUT    => Array
                0   => http://www.domain.com/
            IP       => Array
                0   => 10.20.30.40
            SITE     => Array
                0   => http://www.domain.com/
        SYSTEM      => Array
            ERROR   => Array
                0   => Unable to properly scan your site. Timeout reached
        VERSION     => Array
            DBDATE    => Array
                0   => 03 Jul 2019 15:05 UTC
            VERSION   => Array
                0   => 2.6
        cached      => [boolean] false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My PHP was updated and the `max_execution_time` setting was reset to 30 seconds, which wasn't enough for SiteCheck to completely scan the site. When I increased the execution time to somewhere above 120 seconds, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**The scan failed to properly scan the site issue fix.**

I'm using ithemes security plugin. if you are also seeing error like this give screenshot. click on "show details" copy IP address. and

> `whitelist IP in cloudflare setting.`

if you are using cloudflare.

following steps: cloudflare account>>security>>WAF>>Tools and paste IP address, action- allow, Zone- this website, then click on "Add" button.

now check again itheme security scan, it will be working.